# Finding the value of theta using the $6$ trigonometric functions on an $xy$ plane.

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Here's a link of what I am trying to learn about.

http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/learn/math/lessons/lesson03/3_05.htm

Now I have one question. How will I find the value for theta in each function if the hypotenuse has no exact square root and is now a decimal.

Let $(14,5)$ be a point on the terminal side.

$x = 14$

$y = 5$
\begin{align*}
r & = \sqrt{14^2+5^2}\\
r & = \sqrt{196+25}\\
r & = \sqrt{221}\\
r & = 14.86
\end{align*}

What do I need to do with the calculator?

Comment: What does the $14.5$ in parentheses represent?  Is it supposed to be the length of the terminal side, an angle measure, or a problem number?  Also, do you wish to find exact or approximate values for the trigonometric functions of angle $\theta$?

Comment: x is opposite, y is adjacent and r is hypotenuse. In the link I posted, the formulas are there. sinθ = y/r, cos = x/r, tan = y/x etc. I'm trying to find out What to do When it comes in decimal form. (the hypotenuse)

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a now deleted comment, it is my understanding that the terminal side of the angle passes through the point $(14, 5)$.  You used the Pythagorean Theorem to conclude correctly that $r = \sqrt{221}$.

[image: first-quadrant_angle]

Using the trigonometric formulas
\begin{align*}
\sin\theta & = \frac{y}{r} & \csc\theta & = \frac{r}{y}\\
\cos\theta & = \frac{x}{r} & \sec\theta & = \frac{r}{x}\\
\tan\theta & = \frac{y}{x} & \tan\theta & = \frac{x}{y}
\end{align*}
with the values $x = 14$, $y = 5$, and $r = \sqrt{221}$ yields the exact values
\begin{align*}
\sin\theta & = \frac{5}{\sqrt{221}} & \csc\theta & = \frac{\sqrt{221}}{5}\\
\cos\theta & = \frac{14}{\sqrt{221}} & \sec\theta & = \frac{\sqrt{221}}{14}\\
\tan\theta & = \frac{5}{14} & \tan\theta & = \frac{14}{5}
\end{align*}
Now that we have the exact values, we can plug them into the calculator to obtain the approximations
\begin{align*}
\sin\theta & \approx 0.34 & \csc\theta & \approx 2.97\\
\cos\theta & \approx 0.94 & \sec\theta & \approx 1.06\\
\tan\theta & \approx 0.36 & \cot\theta & = 2.8
\end{align*}
where I have rounded to the nearest hundredth except for $\cot\theta$.  The value for $\cot\theta$ is exact.